# Drag and Drop bodies onto slots of the same shape only using LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

It has been a few since a started playing with LibGDX.

Now I am tryin g to drag and drop bodies onto slots of the same shape:
E.g. Squares can only be dropped onto squares of the same size or bigger. The same for triangles and circles.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java

My point of start is the sample above, but I have no idea put everything together.

1 - What would be the easiest way to implement?

2 - Should I used Box2D and [Physics Body Editor](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/)  to create a polygon shape and use it in the drop method to test the dragged shape with the static shape?

3 - How to test the vertices/edges using Vector2 to see if its is bigger or not?

Hope I am on the right direction.

Comment: You are on a pretty wrong track here. The `DragAndDrop` is just for `scene2d`, it has nothing to do with Box2D at all. Drag and drop with Box2D has to be done via `Joint`s.

Comment: Thanks @noone...would the best approach be PolygonRegion + DragAndDrop?

Comment: PolygonRegion won't help you at all. It has nothing to do with either box2d or scene2d. As I said, the only approach with Box2D is via Joints. If you don't have to use Box2D, then use `Stage` with `DragAndDrop` and implement your own `Actor`s.